# Thread in RUNNABLE state but stack trace shows it is processing?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, stack-trace

After taking *Thread Dump* for a Java Application, several thread snapshots are presented as follows:

```
Thread t@384
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at xmlpdf.text.Word.allocateArrays(Word.java:205)
    at xmlpdf.text.Word.calculateWidth(Word.java:237)
    at xmlpdf.text.TextFormatter.format(TextFormatter.java:167)
    at xmlpdf.text.TextFormatter.formatToWidthImpl(TextFormatter.java:116)
    at xmlpdf.text.TextBlock.formatToWidthImpl(TextBlock.java:71)
    at xmlpdf.tables.TextCell.formatToWidthImpl(TextCell.java:45)
    at xmlpdf.tables.Cell.formatToWidth(Cell.java:349)
    at xmlpdf.tables.Row.assignCellWidths(Row.java:97)
    at xmlpdf.tables.Table.layout(Table.java:354)
    at xmlpdf.tables.Table.formatRowsToWidth(Table.java:329)
    at xmlpdf.tables.Table.formatToWidthImpl(Table.java:373)
    at xmlpdf.Block.formatToWidth(Block.java:57)
    at xmlpdf.renderer.Page.formatWidthAndHeight(Page.java:200)
    at xmlpdf.renderer.Page.addBlockWhichIsNotFooterWholePagesOnly(Page.java:1026)
    .....
```

several same threads (identified by *Thread Name*) are in exactly same state.

F.Y.I. Examining via JMX also shows these threads are running for 4 hours.

**Question:**

How can a thread be in a `RUNNABLE` state and yet the `Stack Trace` of it shows it is doing something?

I thought `RUNNABLE` always means thread is just **available** to process any new task instead of processing the task.

Comment: `RUNNABLE` means that the thread is executing, this is in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html).

Comment: I wish a thread executing were called RUNNING instead..RUNNABLE seems to imply - it could run if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thread.State.RUNNABLE API: *A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual machine but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating system such as processor*

Comment: Evgeniy Dorofeev> Essentially a thread that is not doing anything, and one that is doing something - both have RUNNABLE state. If not, what is the state of the Thread for first case (not doing anything i.e awaiting some task to be assigned to it)

Comment: a thread waiting for a task to be assigned will typically be in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state. Eg in ThreadPoolExecutor it looks like workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)